# How do you use matplotlib function fill_between with pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a stock price line graph which works,however I wanted to use the fill between function. I have tried passing in the values directly from the series and also creating lists etc. and nothing works. Is this possible?

```
myDF = pd.read_csv('C:/Workarea/OneDrive/PyProjects/Learning/stocks_sentdex/GOOG-LON_TSCO.csv')
print(myDF)

myDF = myDF.set_index('Date')

myDF['Close'].plot()


plt.fill_between(?, 0, ?, alpha=0.3)


plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Check it out')
plt.legend()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09,bottom=0.16, right=0.94,top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

All the examples I have seen use their own data or read from a urllib. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# myDF = pd.read_csv('C:/Workarea/OneDrive/PyProjects/Learning/stocks_sentdex/GOOG-LON_TSCO.csv')
# myDF = myDF.set_index('Date')

myDF = pdata.get_data_google('LON:TSCO', start='2009-01-02', end='2009-12-31')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(myDF.index, 0, myDF['Close'], alpha=0.3, label='LON:TSCO')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.set_title('Check it out')
ax.legend()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.09,bottom=0.16, right=0.94,top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The error message

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'

could occur if either `myDF.index` or `myDF['Close']` is an object array. As a simple example,

```
In [110]: plt.fill_between(np.array([1,2], dtype='O'), 0, np.array([1,2], dtype='O'))
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Chances are it is the `Date` that are mere strings rather than datetime-like objects. To fix this, use `pd.to_datetime(myDF['Date'])` to convert the date strings into datetime-like objects.

```
myDF = pd.read_csv('C:/Workarea/OneDrive/PyProjects/Learning/stocks_sentdex/GOOG-LON_TSCO.csv')
myDF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(myDF['Date'])
myDF = myDF.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: This looks great, however, ideally I would like to achieve the same by reading my own csv file. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: @teshHi: The code you posted to define `myDF` using `pd.read_csv` looks fine to me. Try commenting out the line which starts with `myDF = pdata.get_data_google` and uncommenting the two lines above which define `myDF` using `pd.read_csv`. Is there an error? If so, post the full traceback error message and a sample of the csv file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "testFill.py", line 19, in <module>
    ax.fill_between(myDF.index, 0, myDF['Close'], alpha=0.3, label='LON:TSCO')
  File "..\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4606, in fill_between
    x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))
  File "..\numpy\ma\core.py", line 2299, in masked_invalid condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))

Comment: contd: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''