# Fill_between error python - giving me error: ordinal must be >= 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have the following code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
datamax.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value',color='red',ax=ax)
datamin.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value', color='blue',ax=ax)
plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
plt.xlabel("Date",color='navy',labelpad=15)
plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day (2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown',y=1.08)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),
          fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.fill_between(datamax['Date'],datamax['Data_Value'],datamin['Data_Value'],where = None,color='yellow',alpha=0.25)
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting the error:

**ordinal must be >= 1**

Could anybody give me a helping hand?

I can't understand why the 'fill_between' function is not working.

Comment: Can you check if this helps .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257475/valueerror-ordinal-must-be-1

Comment: @Anshul that sadly doesn;t work for me!

Comment: If you're reading it from a file, please upload the file to a cloud-service and post the link here. If this isn't available, could you post the value of `datamax.head()`?

Comment: The problem is that you're using pandas plotting for the line plots while using standard matplotlib for the fill_between. Both interpret dates quite differently.  You could try `plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'], ...)` in the case pandas uses a categorical x-axis.

Comment: Some related posts: [how-do-you-use-matplotlib-function-fill-between-with-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916343/how-do-you-use-matplotlib-function-fill-between-with-pandas-dataframe), [pandas-and-matplotlib-fill-between-vs-datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329725/pandas-and-matplotlib-fill-between-vs-datetime64), [plotting-fill-between-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222084/plotting-fill-between-in-pandas) ...

Comment: @JohanC thanks my solution below!

Comment: @Anwarvic thanks my solution below!

Comment: @Anshul thanks my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
  plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'],color='yellow',alpha=0.8)
```

Essentially, I was using **pandas plotting for the line plots** while using **standard matplotlib** for the fill_between.

Thus, using `range(len(datamax['Date']))` instead of `datamax['Date'`] overcame this compatibility issue.